# Nodejs -No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: node.js

I am using **node-twitter-api** module in node js. I am facing cross domain issue while redirecting from Localhost to twiter login page.

Issues in details below :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Twitter does not support CORS. That's basically what the message obviously says. And that's how it is. Now what is your question?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now I am using node-twitter-api module in node.js. Session getting lost after redirecting from twitter authentication page. Once twitter authentication is completed , again i am trying to get the request token from session. Here req.session.twitterRequestToken is undefined.